# How can I handle "updates" of content for old users, without affecting new users?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The subject was too vague - let me explain:

I have an application in which I include a navigational chart. If someone bought the application in 2011, they got the 2011 version of the navigational chart.

If someone purchases the application in 2012, they will get the 2012 navigational chart.

However - someone who purchased the application in 2011 should be able to *upgrade* their chart (to the 2012 chart) on a paid basis.

How can I reliably implement this?

Furthermore, if someone purchased the app in 2011, they should *not* be able to simple unload the application and reload it (from the AppStore) and get the updated chart for free.

This is not as simple as a straight-forward "in-app purchase" - because newer purchasers would already have received the update.

P.S. Before you comment on how I am being unfair to existing users, etc by "penalizing" them - please note that it is not the case. As with any and all navigation charts, purchasing one (either electronic or paper) does not necessarily give you the rights to all future ones for free. Futhermore, *I* have chart providers which I am required to pay a royalty for the updates.

Comment: Create a new app and ID and going forward write it so that you can support what it is you wish to do. Either depreciate and remove the old app or leave it there if its still useful to users.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to base this on a single upgradable App, which I think you should, for customer continuity, then you're probably going to need to maintain your own server that manages entitlements based on what has been purchased via In-App purchases, and when.

This process is outlined in Apple's In-App purchase documentation.

Comment: A little vague, but I get what your edging at. See the problems issued in other responses. I already have people who have purchased, with no in-app purchases. These people may not run my app again until Summer 2012, at which point I would not be able to distinguish them from recent purchasers.

Answer (score 1):

> Furthermore, if someone purchased the app in 2011, they should not be
>   able to simple unload the application and reload it (from the
>   AppStore) and get the updated chart for free.

The suggestions that you need to run your own entitlement server sound like they might be correct, and the most technically robust approach. However, that relies on being able to uniquely identify your users to your server, and as noted by JustSid the UDID is not going to be available to a developer. In any case, the UDID identifies unique devices, while purchases are based on AppleIDs, so I'm not sure that would really work. The most unpalatable part would however be the need to maintain your own server for this, adding complexity, if there is another approach.

This partly depends on your pricing. If the price of a new chart is less than or equal to your current app price, then there is one simple approach you could use, if it is acceptable to you. When the 2012 chart becomes available, ship the app with the 2011 map, reduce the price of the app by the price of the 2012 chart, and make the 2012 chart available as an in-app purchase for all users.

I have no idea what your app costs, but here's an example:

> *Currently*
>   App with 2011 chart: $10.
>
> *2012 chart becomes available*
>   Price of app for new purchasers: $5. (Ships with 2011 chart).
>   In-app purchase to 2012 chart: $5.
>   Total: $10
>
> Price of updating app for existing customers: $0.
>   In-app purchase to 2012 chart: $5.
>   Total: $5

New customers pay the same total price as before, existing customers get an update at a 50% discount over buying the app outright. If you were going to do this, you would need to make it very clear in the app store that the $5 purchase was for the platform that gave you a legacy chart, and that a $5 in-app purchase was required to get the 2012 chart, as customers are not accustomed to having to make an in-app purchase immediately after purchase of a paid app.

Alternatively, you might not want to distinguish between upgrades and new purchasers. In that case, just set the price of the app with the 2011 chart to $0 in the app store, with a $10 in-app purchase to get the 2012 chart. Personally, I quite like this approach because having downloaded a free app, people will be much more understanding of the need to make an in-app purchase immediately to get full functionality.

> This is not as simple as a straight-forward "in-app purchase" -
>   because newer purchasers would already have received the update.

This is the tricky bit. The scenario I outline above does not exactly give you what you wanted.

I don't claim to have the definitive word on what is possible with in-app purchases, but the only way I can see that you could achieve this is to sell a new app for 2012 purchasers, while offering the 2012 chart as an in-app purchase within the 2011 app for earlier customers. Two apps in the app store. Not sure Apple would like it.

*Later*
The ideal outcome could be achieved if it was possible to programmatically access the original *purchase* date of the app for the current user (rather than download date), in the same way that you can get details about in app purchases that have occurred. Then you could just say something like (pseudo code):

```
if ((purchaseDate > 1-Dec-2011) || (hasPurchased2012ChartInApp == YES)) {  
    // give access to 2012 charts  
}  
else {  
    // only give access to 2011 charts  
}
```

But... I've not been able so far to find a way to get that original purchase date.

Answer (score 0):

So is the problem that you have a paid app, rather than one that relies entirely on in-app purchase?

You should be able to give them one free chart purchase. Charge for the next one(s).

Comment: I don't exactly follow. If I give "them" one free chart purchase - how do I differentiate the new users from the old users? I don't want the "old" users to use the "free purchase" on the "new" chart.

Comment: Mmm, I think this would have to be in place before the new chart was available.

Comment: Well, the new chart isn't out and available yet - but I still have existing users with the old chart - and I need to make sure there aren't any "gaps".

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the price of the in-app purchase dynamically, you could have it try to restore the users purchases when they first open the app, and if there are no purchases to restore, give them the current purchase for free.  This would ensure that only users who have not yet received any content, wether through initial download or in-app purchase, would be able to receive the new map without additional charge.

A way to achieve similar functionality would be to make it a free app (perhaps with demo content) with non-consumable in-app purchases for each chart.  In newer updates, you could make it so that you can only buy the new version but can still restore purchases and get the old version that way.

Comment: I think the problem is - existing users might not run the program again until spring. So if I did that - then even my OLD users would have "no existing purchases" - and they'd get the new chart.

Comment: If they haven't received any charts yet, why not let them have the latest chart?

Comment: I have to worry about them actually HAVING charts, but then deleting the app, and restoring. They shouldn't get free charts if they do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message to your server the first time the user opens the application. Get the device identifier `UUID/UDID` and post it to your server. I know for the user it might look like your 'stealing' his identity (they say it's a bad thing, but still use google). You can say something like "hey this app will now check if you are allowed to get a free chart" yes/no this would even let them choose not to send the device data.
On the server side you can check if it's a new device and then write the ID in a database or whatever. Now even if the user reload the app and contact the server again you will notice that the id already exist in your DB.

Comment: There are two big problems with this method:

1. Developer access to the UDID is going away.

2. People who *currently* own the 2011 edition will probably not run the program again until Summer, 2012. Therefore, this would be the first time they register and run. I would be unable to distinguish them from new 2012 purchases.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, I am assuming that once 2011 passes, there is no point in getting the 2011 navigational charts (you italicized upgrade in your question, and that's my basis for this assumption) AND you won't be paying any royalty charges for the old maps (I guess it will still work with these charges, but you get less profit, in which case use it as a last resort).

Currently, you're selling the 2011 navigation charts, which comes free when you purchase the app. Once you have the 2012 charts, you will keep the app more or less the same, but you will add the 2012 chart as an in-app purchase for the new version. You will also make the app free once you make that update (at the beginning of 2012) and keep the 2011 charts as a sample (but maybe someone is depending on it, so leave it there; also apple requires that an app be useful once downloaded, and it doesn't require an in-app purchase to be useful).

That way, if someone buys the app in 2011, he doesn't get the 2012 charts for free, unless they upgrade via in-app purchase, in which case, you get your money. He/she also isn't frustrated that the once priced map became free, because it is useless now that 2012 has passed. The person that downloads the app in 2012 for free doesn't get the map for free, he will consider the 2011 charts as a sample, gets impressed (hopefully) and purchase the 2012 ones.

For later years, simply add the 2013 charts, 2014 charts, etc. as in-app purchases and keep the rest the same. You said in a comment, you don't want to leave gaps, so leave the previous maps there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I *am* required to pay royalties (significant ones) on even the older 2011 charts. I am worried about having someone pay $35 for an app, to have them discover that the chart is out-of-date and they'd need to kick in an extra $19 for a chart update.

Comment: Then just have a free one with nothing in it but a sample and have them pay for each year charts separately as an in-app purchase. I am not sure how to model separate prices, like first map $35 and then $19 for updating, but it might be easier once there is no issue with when the user downloaded the app.

Answer (score 0):

What I would like to do for this, is mentioned in the following steps:

- I would maintain a version information (some date or year only) of the application at server side.
- I would send the update information for calendars via push notifications.
- When the user registers himself for push notifications, I will store the application version along with device UDID and the device tokens in the database. (You can also do this via some web service but I am just suggesting my way).
- So I can always check whether to charge the user or not by the help of user's application version and device UDID information.
- If the user Deletes his app and reloads it and registers himself for push notification again, I will not update his application version information.

I hope it helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: UDID support being removed in iOS 5. Similar to other methods, but using Push Notifications rather than in-app purchases.

Comment: @Brad I meant to store device related information and version on server side by any of the possible ways. Using push notifications is not mandatory. Coming to UDID thing, they can remove the current format of UDIDs but they can not remove the concept, they will keep some thing like IMEI number as UniqueIdentifier

Comment: No, they appear to be removing uniqueIdentifier so there will be nothing unique to identify the device without using private frameworks.